# How to show a alert before sending a form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Im trying to show a confirmation button before sending a form in ruby on rails.

The problem is that the solution Im using its not working. First, it shows the alert twice, and after pressing the button 2 times, the form is not sent, and nothing happens.

Here is my code

```
  <%=form_for @transaction, :url => delete_duplicated_items_transactions_path(),:html=>{:class=>"form-horizontal bol-form"} do |f|%>

    <div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var checked = false;
        function selectAll(){
          checked = !checked;
          console.log(checked);
          $("input:checkbox").each(function(){
            $(this).attr('checked', checked);
          });
          return false;
        }
      </script>

      <table class="admin-table data-table" id="usertable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" onclick="selectAll()">Select All</a></th>
            <th>Bill of Lading Name</th>
            <th>Product Lot id</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="bill_of_ladings_body">
          <% duplicated.each do |element|%>
            <tr id="row_user_<%=element["product_lot"].id%>">
              <td><%= check_box_tag "product_lots[]", "#{element["bill_of_lading"].id.to_s};#{element["product_lot"].id.to_s}" %></td>
              <td><%=link_to element["bill_of_lading"].name,edit_bill_of_lading_path(:id => element["bill_of_lading"].id)%></td>
              <td><%= element["product_lot"].id %></td>
            </tr>
          <%end%>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="admin-table data-table">
      <br>
      <td align="right">
        <%=f.button "Remove from Bill of Ladings", name: "transaction_type",value: 'remove', :class=>"btn btn-info","data-loading-text"=>"Processing..."%>      
        <%=f.button "Remove from Bill of Ladings and Recycle", name: "transaction_type", value: 'remove_and_recycle', data:{confirm:'If you proceed, the system will delete the selected Lot IDs from the selected Bill Of Ladings and will then recyle all Lot IDs added on the previous step. Any Lot ID that is not selected on this list will not be removed from the corresponding Bill of Lading/s and will not be recycled. Are you sure you want to continue?'}, :class=>"btn btn-danger" %> 

    </div>

  <% end %>
```

What im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you talk about Alerts and Confirms which are two different things. And you also have an div with class Alert, be more specific.

Second, the correct syntax for rails' ujs "confirm" option is `data: {confirm: 'somestring'}}`, you are missing the "data: " key.

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#confirmations

Also, on that link, right below that "Confirmations" section you have an "Automatic disabling" section since you are using `data-loading-text` and rails can already handle that with `data-disable-with`

Comment: Thanks for the answer arieljuod. But I changed (just updated the question) to what you say and the behavior is still the same (show the alert twice and doesnt send the form)

Comment: Do you see any error on the browser's console or the network tab? Again, be more precise, alert and confirmation are two really different things and you also have a div with class "alert". I don't know if you mean the confirm dialog, if you have some alert dialog somewhere else or you are talking about that `.alert` div. If the `.alert.alert-block` div is not relevant remove it from the question (read SO guide about minimal code for the problem) and fix the wording you are using.

Comment: I just removed the alert.alert-block. Thanks for the feedback. Im talking about confirmations (that pop-ups twice but dont send the form). Nothing is coming from the JS console too

Comment: Does the form work if you remove the `confirm` option? I don't know if it's really needed but try adding a `type: :submit` option to the button tags.

Comment: also, check if you have both rails-ujs and jquery-ujs on your application.js, maybe that's why you have two dialogs